# Hierarchical Clustering Threshold

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering

I'm using the `scikit-learn` module of `agglomerative hierarchical clustering` to obtain clusters of a three million geographical hexagrid using `contiguity constraints` and `ward affinity`.

My question is related to the resulted number of clusters that the routine returns. I know that the ward's affinity minimizes the sums of the within cluster variance. This is trivially minimized when the cluster is just one observation, right? That is why I assume that the algorithm starting point is just a random big number for this variance so that including the nearest contiguous observation (given that is within the max distance threshold) will decrease the variance of the group and it continues this way until it reaches the top of the tree.

My question is what is the criteria used to return the clusters labels. Reading about it seems that the optimum number of clusters is given by when there is a biggest jump in the tree. But I'm not sure if this is the criteria the developers are using. Anyone knows?

Ideally I could check by plotting the tree, but I'm clustering nearly 3 million cells which makes plotting the tree both messy and unfeasible (with my computer or the cluster I have access at least).

Thanks